# Installing google-cloud-bigquery within a Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to install google-cloud-bigquery from within a Jupyter notebook like so:

```
!pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery
```

This runs for a short while, but then trips out with a permissions problem:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 323, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/google_auth-0.6.0-py2.7-nspkg.pth'
```

What does this indicate and how can I fix? I tried running with sudo, but don't know how to enter my password.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv). Instead of using the system Python, Pyenv uses a Python executable in your home directory. It modifies your path so packages get installed in your home partition as well.